# How can I make this MySQL query better in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my web app I have a route that makes two database calls. One gets 15 image paths from the mysql table in descending order and prints them to an `<img>` tag and another that loops the whole table for pagination purposes. So these are two calls which are bound to slow down my web app so how do I optimize the query if possible. Here is the code:

```
router.get('/board', function(req, res){
//GET PAGE NUMBER FOR PAGINATION
if(req.query.page){
    var page = parseInt(req.query.page);
}else{
    page = 1;
}
var start_from = (page - 1) * 15,
    rows,
    total_pages,
    getPages = connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts', function(err, result){
        rows = result.length;
        total_pages = parseInt(Math.ceil(rows / 15));
    }),
    sql = connection.query('SELECT ID, Title, Img_path FROM posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT ' + start_from + ', 15', function(err, result){    
        res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        res.render('board', {print: result, pages: total_pages, page_no: page });
    });
```

});

Comment: `SELECT ID FROM posts` ? What about a `count` query ???

Comment: @ceadreak Yes, that was a stupid mistake. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get the row count instead `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts`, even if the result.length is efficient, you're still retrieving a potentially large number of integers you not actually doing anything with.

As far as the paginated results using `ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT x, 15`, the most likely suggestion to help there (because it does require ordering the entire table every time) is to instead change it to a `WHERE ID BETWEEN (x-1) and (x - 15) ORDER BY ID DESC` (without a limit), where x is the lowest id retrieved on the previous query/page.

Of course that complicates going "back" and "forward". You could make the first query something like `SELECT (ID-1) DIV 15 AS pageNum, MIN(ID), MAX(ID) FROM posts GROUP BY pageNum`, and actually save the results to an array and use them as known page boundaries. The downsides to that are: (1) you will need to tweak the displayed page number so that the higher ID values are not on the last page, and (2) will to check at intervals if any new images have been added. If the ID is an auto increment, this should simply be a matter of checking if there is anything above the highest max you currently have.

Also, if you have gaps between ID values you may end up with some pages having less than 15 (or pages missing altogether if no ID numbers that would've fallen in that range are present.)